# Save the stream from the speaker

Tags: python, audio-streaming

I have a Python issue. I want to save the music stream form my speaker or from an audio player.

For example:
I have [this url with a web music player](http://skinsparty.free.fr/pro/Bretagne/Matmatah%20-%20La%20Fille%20du%20Chat%20Noir.mp3)

And I would like to save the music on my computer.
I made some research to find an API or piece of code but this wasn't really helpfull.

So my questions are:

- is it possible to save an audio stream form a web media player ?
- if  yes, is it easier to save it from the speaker or is it some other
  way?

I just want advice or informations about saving an audio stream with Python, so if you have any please help me.

Comment: That particular URL just points to an MP3 file you can download in your web browser by right clicking on it. You can use `urllib2.urlopen` to access it programically in Python.

Comment: thanks, I did not notice the fact that the file was open, I thought it was loaded by the player.
Actually, I'm sad it is so easily :'( I wished it will be more complex.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  If you have found a solution to your problem, the correct action is to provide an answer, and after a short delay, accept it as the correct answer.